# Why is current_time different from both current_timestamp and now() in PostgreSQL 12 when using JDBC?

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, time

When I run the following query in PgAdmin4 or psql, I get the same values for `current_time`, `now()`, and `current_timestamp`:

```
SELECT now(), CURRENT_TIME, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP;
              now              |    current_time    |       current_timestamp
-------------------------------+--------------------+-------------------------------
 2020-04-27 11:54:55.443006+01 | 11:54:55.443006+01 | 2020-04-27 11:54:55.443006+01
```

But when I run the same query from within DBeaver by connecting to the same PostgreSQL database, using JDBC driver, there's a **difference** between `current_time` and `now()` (and `current_timestamp`):

```
now                |current_time|current_timestamp  |
-------------------|------------|-------------------|
2020-04-27 12:57:00|    11:57:00|2020-04-27 12:57:00|
```

Obviously, the JDBC driver is somehow creating a discrepancy between `current_time` and `current_timestamp`.

My questions:

- Is this the expected behavior from JDBC driver? (Why?)
- Is there a way to control this behavior via some configuration of the JDBC driver itself without modifying the applications and queries relying on the JDBC driver?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`current_time` is a `time WITH time zone` something that is not supported by JDBC.

Applications need to take special steps to retrieve that value correctly. So, yes this is somewhat expected. I guess DBEaver uses `getTime()` which returns the time as UTC

That's one of the reasons the use of `current_time` [is discouraged](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/Don%27t_Do_This#Don.27t_use_CURRENT_TIME)